# How to serialize two object with `one-to-many` relationship?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I have two classes: `Lookup` and `LookupItem` that `Lookup` has a member named `Items` that is a collection of `LookupItem`s. I'm not able to serialize `Lookup` or `LookupItem`. With the first I get error `The type LookupItem was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.` and with the second I got error `A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type Lookup.`.

How can I solve this problem?

I use following code for serialization:

```
public static string Serialize(object obj)
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
    ser.Serialize(writer, obj);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**UPDATE:**
skeleton of classes:

[ActiveRecord(Lazy = true)]
public class Lookup : ActiveRecordExtender, IComparable
{
    public Lookup()
    {
    }

```
[Property]
public virtual string Title { set; get; } 

// creating relation
[HasMany(typeof(LookupItem), Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.All)]
public virtual IList Items { set; get; }
```

}

[ActiveRecord(Lazy = true)]
public class LookupItem : ActiveRecordExtender
{
    public LookupItem()
    {
    }

```
//creating relation
[BelongsTo("Lookup_ID")]
public virtual Lookup ContainerLookup { set; get; }

[Property]
public virtual string Title { set; get; } 

[Property]
public virtual string Value { set; get; } 

[Property]
public virtual int SortOrder { set; get; }
```

}

Please note I'm using Catle ActiveRecord as my ORM and please notice this problem is not related to inheritance from `ActiveRecordBase`. Because other classes in this domain that has no relations work properly.

Comment: can you include Lookup and LookupItem class skeleton in your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a blog post and its comments [here](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/147218.aspx#745524) and if assume there is no need to related data, adding `[XmlIgnore]` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to serialize nested classes.

Have a look at similar post 
[C# System.Xml.Serialization Self-nested elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851454/c-system-xml-serialization-self-nested-elements)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/Serializing_Nested_XML.aspx